# Define bash variable to be evaluated every time it is used

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

I want to define bash a variable which will be evaluated every time it is used.

My goal is to define two variables:

```
A=/home/userA
B=$A/my_file
```

So whenever I update `A`, `B` will be updated with the new value of `A`
I know how to do it in prompt variables, but, is there a way to do it for regular variables?

Comment: Did you consider defining a function?

Comment: `I know how to do it in prompt variables` what are prompt variables and how do you do that? `B` is not "defined" to be `'<get A> + '/my_file'` it is defined to `/home/userA/my_file`.

Comment: That's not what variables do. Variables store data, not procedures for generating data.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Bash 4.4 or newer, you could (ab)use the `${parameter@P}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which expands *`parameter`* as if it were a prompt string:

```
$ A='/home/userA'
$ B='$A/my_file'      # Single quotes to suppress expansion
$ echo "${B@P}"
/home/userA/my_file
$ A='/other/path'
$ echo "${B@P}"
/other/path/my_file
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, it's much simpler and more portable to use a function instead:

```
$ appendfile() { printf '%s/%s\n' "$1" 'my_file'; }
$ A='/home/user'
$ B=$(appendfile "$A")
$ echo "$B"
/home/user/my_file
$ A='/other/path'
$ B=$(appendfile "$A")
$ echo "$B"
/other/path/my_file
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Use a simple and robust function instead:

```
b() {
  echo "$a/my_file"
}

a="/home/userA"
echo "b outputs $(b)"

a="/foo/bar"
echo "b outputs $(b)"
```

Result:

```
b outputs /home/userA/my_file
b outputs /foo/bar/my_file
```

---

That said, here's one ugly way of fighting the system accomplish your goal verbatim:

```
# Trigger a re-assignment after every single command
trap 'b="$a/my_file"' DEBUG

a="/home/userA"
echo "b is $b"

a="/foo/bar"
echo "b is $b"
```

Result:

```
b is /home/userA/my_file
b is /foo/bar/my_file
```